# Reference variable defined more than once

Tags: c++

In C++, once a reference variable has been defined to refer to a particular variable, can it refer to any other variable?

My code I was using for testing is below:

```
int r1 =1001;
int r2  =10023;
int &r3 = r1;
r3 = r2;
r3 = 999;
r3 = 555;
int r4 = 11;
r3 = r4;
r3 = 10177;
cout<<r3<<endl;
cout<<r1<<endl;
cout<<r2<<endl;
cout<<r4<<endl;
```

The output:

```
10177
10177
10023
11
```

Comment: no. you cannot even leave out the initialization for a reference.

Comment: Which part are you confused about?

Comment: `r3 = r2;` is assigning value of r2 to r3 not the reference. So they still point to different memory locations but with same values after this statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Once a reference variable has been defined to refer to a particular variable it can refer to any other variable in C plus plus?

**No**. References are bound at initialization and cannot be re-bound. After initialization, a reference is just an **alias** for the object it is bound to - and references must *always* be initialized.

In other words, whatever you do on the reference is done on the *object* being referenced. Here, for instance:

```
int &r3 = r1;
```

You are binding `r3` to `r1`, so `r3` will be an alias for `r1` (like an alternative name). This means that the subsequent assignment:

```
r3 = r2;
```

Does **not** re-bind `r3` to refer to `r2`: instead, it ends up assigning `r2` to `r1`. Knowing this, you should be able to figure out the behavior of the rest of your program.

Comment: you could mention about declaration without initialization being illegal for references.

Comment: +1. Andy why dont you update your profile? more than thinking about the possible solution to questions and learn when i come here to SO, i'm left wondering who andy prowl is :-).

Comment: its great to see your answer along with other great answers on SO but this will always haunt me:-) hope you update your profile soon :-)

Comment: @Koushik: Sooner or later I will, but don't be disappointed after seeing I'm *really* noone ;)

Comment: but your answers pronounce your name aloud :-)thats all that matters for me "The power of your mind". and hope your not an alien :-)

Comment: @Koushik: Thank you, but you are really celebrating me more than I deserve ;)

Comment: i need to thank you for giving me chance to learn.:-). looking forward to seeing more wonderful answers from you. all the best and please complete the favour soon:-)

Comment: Thank you Very Much.
my confusion is gone.

Answer (score 0):

No, a reference can't be bound to another object after it has been initialised.

```
int r1 =1001;
int r2  =10023;
int &r3 = r1;
r3=r2;
```

Here, `r3` is bound to the object `r1` with value `1001`. Then the name `r3` behaves exactly as if you were using the name `r1` instead - it's like an *alias*. When you assign the value of `r2` to that object, `r1` now contains the value `10023`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code with comments, which may help you understand:

```
int r1 = 1001;  // r1 now holds the value 1001
int r2 = 10023; // r2 now holds the value 10023
int &r3 = r1;  // using r3 is now like using r1
r3=r2;  // same as r1=r2; r1 now holds the value 10023
r3 = 999; // same as r1 = 999; r1 now holds the value 999
r3 = 555; // same as r1 = 555; r1 now holds the value 555
int r4 = 11; // r4 now holds the value 11
r3=r4; // same as r1 = r4; r1 now holds the value 11
r3 = 10177; // same as r1 = 10177; r1 now holds the value 10177
cout<<r3<<endl; // same as printing r1 which is 10177
cout<<r1<<endl; // prints 10177
cout<<r2<<endl; // prints 10023
cout<<r4<<endl; // prints 11
```